# How can I open profile Linkedin application from my Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I want to open LinkedIn user profile details from my flutter appliction.

Answer (score 2):

Try below code hope its helpful to you.

You must use **url_launcher** package from [here](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) add this dependency in your pubspec.yaml file

create one widget

```
InkWell(
      hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
      child: Image.network(
        'https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/174/174857.png',
        width: 70,
        height: 70,
      ),
      onTap: () => _linkedin(),
    )
```

Create ontap function

```
_linkedin() async {
    const url =
        'https://www.linkedin.com';// or add your URL here
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be natively open in your application or get the user's data from LinkedIn website down to your app, you can check out their [APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-api) that you can call and react to the data fetched.