# launch a button(url) and then open browser in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, browser, launch

I want when the `Sign Up` is clicked, the browser be open and go to my website but i dont know how to do that.
here is my code, when i tap on `Sign Up` it doesn't work:

```
    return Container(
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => launch("https://my.drclubs.ir/"),
        child: RichText(
          text: TextSpan(
            children: [
              TextSpan(
                text: "Don\`t have an Account?",
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 18,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
              ),
              TextSpan(
                text: "Sign Up",
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 18,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69465730/13997210)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a package called `url_launcher` [here](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher).

***Example***:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

const _url = 'https://flutter.dev'; /// Put your custom url here.

void main() => runApp(
      const MaterialApp(
        home: Material(
          child: Center(
            child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: _launchURL,
              child: Text('Show Flutter homepage'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

void _launchURL() async =>
    await canLaunch(_url) ? await launch(_url) : throw 'Could not launch $_url';
```

You can try this:

```
return Container(
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: _launchURL,
        child: RichText(
          text: TextSpan(
            children: [
              TextSpan(
                text: "Don\`t have an Account?",
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 18,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
              ),
              TextSpan(
                text: "Sign Up",
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 18,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```