# Flutter Web View & URL Launcher iOS

Tags: ios, flutter

We have built a web view app, with Flavors, that when a user clicks an external link, a link not within the website's URL, it will navigate them off the app to Safari (iOS).

This works fine on our Android apps, but when I run it on an iOS device it just opens all the URLs within the website.

Context: We use flavors so the URL is coming from another dart file, appURL.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

var flavorConfigProvider;

var fetchColor;

void mainCommon(FlavorConfig config) {
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
      SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarBrightness: Brightness.light));
  flavorConfigProvider = StateProvider((ref) => config);
  runApp(
    ProviderScope(
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: context.read(flavorConfigProvider).state.appURL,
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String stringResponse;
  Map mapResponse;

  Future fetchData() async {
    http.Response response;
    response = await http.get(context.read(flavorConfigProvider).state.apiURL);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      setState(() {
        mapResponse = json.decode(response.body);
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    fetchData();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
      color: HexColor.fromHex(mapResponse['brand_color'].toString()),
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          child: Column(children: [
            Expanded(
              child: WebView(
                initialUrl: context.read(flavorConfigProvider).state.appURL,
                javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {
                  if (request.url.startsWith(
                      context.read(flavorConfigProvider).state.appURL)) {
                    return NavigationDecision.navigate;
                  } else {
                    _launchURL(request.url);
                    return NavigationDecision.prevent;
                  }
                },
              ),
            )
          ]),
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }

  _launchURL(String url) async {
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(
        url,
        
        
      );
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }
}

class HexColor {
  static Color fromHex(String hexString) {
    final buffer = StringBuffer();
    if (hexString.length <= 7) buffer.write('ff');
    buffer.write(hexString.replaceFirst('#', ''));

    return Color(int.parse(buffer.toString(), radix: 16));
  }
}
```

Comment: refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69465730/13997210) hope its helpful to you.

Comment: The issue I'm facing is that it is opening every URL on the website