# How to launch Amazon app using product link in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, url-launcher

I want to open Amazon App when someone press the elevated button. I am using `url_launcher` package and using affiliate product link.

```
ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        launch("https://www.amazon.com/");
      },
      child: Text("amazon"),
    ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code hope its helpful to you.

You must use **`url_launcher`** package from [here](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) add this dependency in your pubspec.yaml file

You can refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69465730/13997210) also for open app from URL

create one widget

```
InkWell(
      hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
      child: Image.network(
        'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/de/Amazon_icon.png',
        width: 70,
        height: 70,
      ),
      onTap: () => amazon(),
    )
```

Create ontap function

```
amazon() async {
    const url =
        'https://www.amazon.com/';// or add your URL here
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thankyou so much for your help.

Comment: Happy to help you out enjoy your ride with flutter