# Unable to launch google meet via link through flutter application

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-meet, url-launcher

I am trying to build an application where users can join google meet just with one click(I know it is easier to send a meet link via Whatsapp but I want everything in one place). I have used the [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) package since google meet generates a URL for every meeting. Every other URL works fine except for the google meet link. Whenever I pass the google meet URL as the parameter to the parse function, it redirects me to a "web page not available" in the emulator(even on a real device).

How do I make the user redirect to that particular meeting and join on the meet app?

```
final Uri url = Uri.parse("https://meet.google.com/rxf-uxca-jpx");
  void _launchUrl() async {
    if (!await launchUrl(url)) throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
```

```
ElevatedButton(
                    child: const Text(
                      'Click here to join',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 25,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    onPressed: _launchUrl,
                  ),
```

I even made these changes in my AndroidManifest.xml file as given in the [docs](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher), I don't know if this is required or not.

```
<queries>
  <!-- If your app opens https URLs -->
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />
  </intent>
</queries>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. It opens google meet app on your phone. Just paste your google meet link in the url field.

```
googleMeet() async {
    const url = 'your google meet url link';
    final uri = Uri.parse(url);
      await launchUrl(uri, mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);
  }
```

Comment: You should add a description to your code.

Answer (score -1):

Try below code, Its working on my machine, refer my answer [**`here`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70578393/13997210) for same.

Your googleMeet function with URL:

```
googleMeet() async {
  const url = 'https://meet.google.com/rxf-uxca-jpx';
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}
```

Your Widget:

```
   ElevatedButton(
        child: Text(
          'Click here to join',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 25,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
        onPressed: () => googleMeet(),
      ),
```

Comment: ` I/UrlLauncher(18357): component name for meet.google.com/rxf-uxca-jpx is null I/UrlLauncher(18357): component name for flutter.dev is null ` I tried the same solution you suggested, and I got the above statements in the debug console and I got an exception pointing to this line. `throw 'Could not launch $url'; `

Comment: Not able to launch any website.