# I want to open Amazon associate links in the app with url_launcher

Tags: flutter, flutterwebviewplugin, url-launcher

I am currently using url_launcher.
"mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication" and if I tap the link I want to show the Amazon app.

But I can't do that.

Probably because I am using Amazon Associates links.

I could not solve the problem.

code

```
   Future _launchUniversalLinkIos(int index) async {
    final url = reversedList[index].acf!.link.toString();
    try {
      await launchUrl(
        Uri.parse(url),
      );
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint('Laucnh url Error: $e');
    }
  }
```

```
                      PageView(
                        controller: _pageController,
                        onPageChanged: (page) {
                          setState(() {
                            selectedPage = page;
                          });
                        },
                        children: pages.map((image) {
                          return GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () =>
                                // final index = pages.indexOf(image);
                                _launchUniversalLinkIos(
                              pages.indexOf(image),
                            ),
                            child: AspectRatio(
                              aspectRatio: 4 / 3,
                              child: Image.network(
                                image,
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        }).toList(),
                      ),
```

print result
flutter: https://amzn.to/xxxxxxxx

info.plist

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>itms-beta</string>
            <string>itms</string>
        </array>
```

I did try amzn and com.amazon.mobile.shopping
but I can not open amazon app

Comment: refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70578393/13997210) hope its help to  you

Comment: Thanks for your comment .My link is https://amzn.to/xxxx .

Comment: just pass your link to my link

Comment: I looked at your code.
I am trying to figure out how to modify it.

I have changed my code.
I added the code of the caller.

Comment: your updated code is working?

Comment: no , maybe my code is bad

Comment: I check your url its not correct, if im heat your link it gives this https://www.amazon.com/ and your url is https://amzn.to/xxxxxxxx and its gives null response like `component name for https://amzn.to/xxxxxxxx is null` change your url

Comment: Do you know why this code is not working properly?

Comment: I want answer on here

Comment: Just min give mw some time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250185/discussion-between-ravindra-s-patil-and-tdayo).

Comment: please check the messages in [chats](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250185/discussion-between-ravindra-s-patil-and-tdayo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code your problem has been solved just remove if else block from function:

Widget:

```
   GestureDetector(
          
          child: Image.network(
            'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/de/Amazon_icon.png',
            width: 70,
            height: 70,
          ),
          onTap: () => amazon(),
        ),
```

Function:

```
  amazon() async {
    const url = 'https://amzn.to/xxxxxxxx'; // or add your URL here
    await launchUrl(Uri.parse(url));
  }
```

Add below code into your `Info.plist` file [`myproject/ios/Runner/Info.plist`]

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>http</string>
    <string>https</string>
</array>
```

Result-> [image]

Comment: my code use "return GestureDetector()". So i can not use Inkwell

Comment: @Tdayo I have updated my answer please check you can used `GestureDetector` instead of `InkWell`

Comment: Sorry , I forgot that It use in PageVIew widget. I fixed code

Comment: If your problem has been solved by my solution/answer please upvote and accept it

Comment: offcourse, but i can not yet

Comment: I need "final index = pages.indexOf(image);"  Because It have on carousel

Comment: @Tdayo I cant understand what do you want as per your above question I have post correct answer

Comment: I did change code .I want check. but it opened safari.

Comment: @Tdayo it gives like this error `Insecure HTTP is not allowed by platform in Flutter IOS`?or check my updated answer

Comment: I can open link , but I can not open amazon app . I added info.plist . but same.

Comment: I not use android . This is iPhone.

Comment: @Tdayo my answer is working on both