# How to mock url_launcher package for flutter test?

Tags: flutter, testing, mocking, mockito, url-launcher

I used [url_launcher: ^6.1.0](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) in my flutter project.
I start to write tests for my widgets, but the part of widgets that used the **url_launcher** method to launch an URL, not worked properly when running the test.

One of the methods that I used inside my Widget is like below method:

```
 Future<void> _onTapLink(String? href) async {
    if (href == null) return;

    // canLaunchUrl method never return anything when we are calling this function inside flutter test
    if (await canLaunchUrl(Uri.parse(href))) {
      await launchUrl(Uri.parse(href));
    } else {
      print('cannot launch url: $href');
    }
  }
```

**canLaunchUrl** method never returns anything when we are calling this function inside the flutter test.

> I'm looking for a way to mock the [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) package for using inside
> flutter tests.

Comment: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69465730/13997210) answer

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil it did not work for me, when I run test coverage and it shows the result of canLaunch method never returned

Comment: I think the only way is to wrap the launchURl and canLaunchURL method in an own class. Then you can mock this class in your test. It´s always a good idea to put external libraries behind a facade.

Answer (score 7):

To mock [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) you may:

1. Add [plugin_platform_interface](https://pub.dev/packages/plugin_platform_interface) and [url_launcher_platform_interface](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher_platform_interface) packages to `dev_dependencies` section in the `pubspec.yaml` file.
2. Implement the mock class. For example, with [mocktail](https://pub.dev/packages/mocktail) the implementation would be:

```dart
import 'package:mocktail/mocktail.dart';
import 'package:plugin_platform_interface/plugin_platform_interface.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher_platform_interface/url_launcher_platform_interface.dart';

class MockUrlLauncher extends Mock
    with MockPlatformInterfaceMixin
    implements UrlLauncherPlatform {}
```

Notice that here `MockPlatformInterfaceMixin` mixin is used.

3. Configure the mock as usual. With mocktail that might be:

```dart
MockUrlLauncher setupMockUrlLauncher() {
  final mock = MockUrlLauncher();
  registerFallbackValue(const LaunchOptions());

  when(() => mock.launchUrl(any(), any())).thenAnswer((_) async => true);
  return mock;
}
```

4. Tell `url_launcher` to use mocked version by setting it in `UrlLauncherPlatform.instance`:

```dart
final mock = setupMockUrlLauncher();
UrlLauncherPlatform.instance = mock;
```

Comment: argument to `thenAnswer` is failing, what worked for me was: `(_) => () async => Future<bool>.value(true)`

Answer (score 1):

[This is an article](https://www.christianfindlay.com/blog/flutter-mock-functions-for-testing) that explicitly explains how to mock or fake the `launchUrl` function. Here is an example of how to mock it with [mocktail](https://pub.dev/packages/mocktail). It also uses the [ioc_container](https://pub.dev/packages/ioc_container) package to handle substitution with dependency injection.

```dart
import 'package:fafsdfsdf/main.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:mocktail/mocktail.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LaunchMock extends Mock {
  Future<bool> call(
    Uri url, {
    LaunchMode? mode,
    WebViewConfiguration? webViewConfiguration,
    String? webOnlyWindowName,
  });
}

void main() {
  testWidgets('Test Url Launch', (tester) async {
    //These allow default values
    registerFallbackValue(LaunchMode.platformDefault);
    registerFallbackValue(const WebViewConfiguration());

    //Create the mock
    final mock = LaunchMock();
    when(() => mock(
          flutterDevUri,
          mode: any(named: 'mode'),
          webViewConfiguration: any(named: 'webViewConfiguration'),
          webOnlyWindowName: any(named: 'webOnlyWindowName'),
        )).thenAnswer((_) async => true);

    final builder = compose()
      //Replace the launch function with a mock
      ..addSingletonService<LaunchUrl>(mock);

    await tester.pumpWidget(
      builder.toContainer()<MyApp>(),
    );

    //Tap the icon
    await tester.tap(
      find.byIcon(Icons.favorite),
    );

    await tester.pumpAndSettle();

    verify(() => mock(flutterDevUri)).called(1);
  });
}
```